# Firestore unable to create new indexes

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 firestore collections (with 20 million record in each one) that can't create new indexes on them anymore, if I make a new index it goes into Building status, after sometime it shows Something Went Wrong, then it disappears, if it try to make the same index again it shows index already exists, I tried checking/creating the index from both firestore console and Google Cloud Console and both have same behavior.

Anyone faced this before and could fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I think that most likely you should contact the Firebase team.

Comment: Would you be able to clarify what you mean by "then it disappears"?  What happens if you do `gcloud firestore indexes composite list` and `gcloud firestore operations list`.  I'm guessing you are talking about building a composite index vs changing your single field indexing.